# mat-select value doesn't work with formControlName

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using mat-select ,I need to set default value for it. It works but After adding formControlName to it, its default value is not displayed.

I tried [(ngModel)] and [(value)] , and "mat-autocomplete"

```
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-select placeholder="پیش نمایش" 
   formControlName="lesson" 
     [value]="free_demo"
      (selectionChange)="onSelectDemo(i)">
      <mat-option [value]="demo.id"
       *ngFor="let demo of demos[i]">
        {{ demo.title }}
       </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using "formControlName" you can access the controller in the TS file and set value like:

```
this.yourFormName.controls['lesson'].setValue('your value or' + this.dynamicValue )
```

Comment: I tried a simple input and named it `formControlName="lesson"` and also add 
`subProduct.controls.lesson.setValue(result.sub_products[i].lesson)` . It Works . But in `mat-select` it dosnt work

Comment: well the value you are assigning to each of the option is derived from your object demos[ i ] and you are trying to setValue of some result's sub object. If both the objects are not the same the chances are that the setValue Data does not match any value on the mat select. It would be better to provide us with the .ts and the object value.

Comment: But when I  remove the ` formControlName="lesson"` and give a static value , It dos work! the problem is with  formControlName

Comment: well it would be great if you could provide a stackblitz replica of the problem

Comment: It's a big project and take too much time for me to create   stackblitz  . I did `console.log(FormGroup)` . my formcontrol has been set value correctly. It's just not displaying
`lesson: FormControl
asyncValidator: null

invalid: (...)
parent: (...)
pending: (...)
pristine: true
root: (...)
status: "VALID"
statusChanges: EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
touched: false
untouched: (...)
updateOn: (...)
valid: (...)
validator: null
value: "ویرایش رکورد موجود در پایگاه داده"`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-set-default-value-of-mat-select-when-options-are-retriev - a small replica of mat select set value. If you have followed the same procedure and its not working there might be some other mistakes outside the syntax to set value for which a thorough code review must be done.

Comment: My code are correct ! but i dont know whats the problem!!bytheway I solved the problem by using `mat-outocomplete` insted of `mat-select` !  tnx for your responses dude :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
Make sure to update your components module with the correct import of `MatSelectModule`.

```
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ....
    MatSelectModule,
  ],
}
```

Unfortunetly, the error message is not really self-explaining.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to using reactive forms, I would recommend you to set/update your `FormControl` by using the `setValue()` or `patchValue()` methods. You may read up more about it over [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#updating-parts-of-the-data-model).

This is one way you can update your form values using patchValue. Assuming the object has a id of `1`,

```
this.editProductForm.patchvalue({
  sub_products: [{
    lesson: '1'
  }]
});
```

On your component.ts,

```
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-select placeholder="پیش نمایش" 
   formControlName="lesson" 
   (selectionChange)="onSelectDemo(i)">
   <mat-option [value]="demo.id" *ngFor="let demo of demos[i]">
     {{ demo.title }}
   </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Actually I did this , but it dosnt work too,


`const subProducts = this.editProductForm.get('sub_products') as FormArray;
subProduct.controls.lesson.setValue(result.sub_products[i].lesson);`

Comment: I have updated my answer. This will set the value for the first FormControl within the `sub_products` FormArray

Comment: I have 4 formControl in Sub_product FormArray

Comment: I tried a simple input and named it `formControlName="lesson"` and also add 
`subProduct.controls.lesson.setValue(result.sub_products[i].lesson)` . It Works . But in `mat-select` it dosnt work

Comment: @mahsayadegari Just to check, why is there a `demos[i]` at the `ngfor`? SHouldn't it just be `demos`?

Answer (score 1):

When you don't use `formControlName` and set the static `[value]` as default it becomes a completely different scenario and the `mat-select` is no longer a member of the form and
[you just set the value manually](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/select/select.ts#L378), so `formControlName` does nothing but syncs a `FormControl` in an existing `FormGroup` to a form control element by name, if you define default value in constructor of `FromControl` but nothing happened so you have to check the type of [comparison](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/select_control_value_accessor.ts#L120)  of the default value and the values ​​that you defined as value for every `mat-option` because `mat-select` uses its own `ControlValueAccessor` or you can implement your own by passing a [function to `[compareWith]` input](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#customizing-option-selection). (پیش نمایش؟؟ :))

Answer (score 0):

One reason for this issue could be an incompatibility in the type of values that you are using in `mat-option`'s value and the value that you are setting for its formControlName. For example, I used form builder group like this:

```
return this.formBuilder.group({
    car_select: { value: "SOME VALUE WHICH IS IN STRING!", disabled: false },
});
```

and in the html:

```
<mat-select formControlName="car_select">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let car of cars" [value]="car.id.toString()">
        {{car.name}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

the `value` in `mat-option` accepts `any` type, so you need to make sure that you are passing the correct type which is `string`, in this case.